# How to Import or add App Inventor 2 ".keystore" file to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, app-inventor, android-keystore

I was previously using App Inventor 2 to create android apps but recently I migrated to Android Studio, but I have uploaded an app  created from App Inventor 2 to Google Play Store which has over 1k downloads. Now I'm trying to recreate that app using Android Studio but I don't want to loose my users so I'm using the same project name and the keystore.

But the problem is that i have downloaded the keystore file which has ".keystore" file extension from App Inventor 2 and I don't know how to import it to Android Studio.

I have also tried setting the keystore path of that file  but then I get confused how to fill the fields of keystore password , key alias and key password; since I don't know these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally Found It: App Inventor generates these default values:

Default Keystore Password: *android*
Default Key Password: *android*
Default Keystore Alias: *androidkey*